# SBT: Unable to resolved dependencies for date range picker

Tags: reactjs, playframework, sbt, daterangepicker, webjars

I am trying to use this React based date range picker in my Play 2.5/Scala application:

https://github.com/onefinestay/react-daterange-picker

However, one of the dependencies cannot be found:

```
[warn]  :: org.webjars.npm#calendar;0.2.1: not found
[warn]  :: org.webjars.npm#calendar;[0.1.0,0.2): not found
...
[error] (common/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.webjars.npm#calendar;0.2.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.webjars.npm#calendar;[0.1.0,0.2): not found
```

There is no such package as "calendar" in webjars.org repository. Has the name changed? Any idea how I can make this datepicker build successfully ?

Answer (score 1):

I found `react-datepicker` and `react-bootstrap-daterangepicker`.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.webjars.npm" % "react-datepicker" % "0.12.0"
```

or

```
libraryDependencies += "org.webjars.npm" % "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker" % "1.0.4"
```

Comment: Thanks - with these lines I dont get any build error but I really liked the look and feel of "onefinestay" version.. I am still stuck with that error